# "Error in loading DLL" when compiling DLL in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a visual basic 6 ".dll project" that uses references and when "File->Make dll" option is clicked, it should generate a dll file. Well, when clicked "File->Make dll", I get error "Error in loading DLL".

How can I see which references are missing?

Comment: Welcome. There's no need to put a signature on the bottom, it's already included just below your post. You amy want to check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) as well.

Comment: Can't you step through the code and see where it is blowing up?

Comment: No Mark, I cannot. "Step Over", "Step Into", "Start", "Start with full compile" - all of them return "Error in loading DLL"

Comment: Is this some specific option for vb6? Where can I find it?

Comment: If running under Win 7 with UAC, have you tried launching VB6 via "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: No, I don't use Win 7. I work under Win XP. But, also I tried "Run as administrator" and it didn't succeed

Comment: Is what a specific option for vb6? What was the result of trying a compile?

Comment: Deanna, I did "Step Over", "Step Into", "Start", "Start with full compile" - all of them return "Error in loading DLL". Is there anything else similar to this that I can try? Where can I find it?

Comment: The Compile option only compiles the project, not run it and can be found on the File menu labelled "Make blah.exe"

Comment: I did it (please read my very first post)

Answer (score 2):

Under Project -> References.

Look for the word MISSING:  in front of the dll's that aren't there.

Comment: there are no "MISSING" labeled references, but when build, I get the mentioned error :(

Comment: Do you have vs6 service pack 6 installed? If not, install it, and try one more time.

Comment: already tried, but without any success. Can you provide a link where you have downloaded it, please?

Comment: Here's microsoft's download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9183

Comment: Tried with this one too, but without success. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this error occur when referenced components are recompiled with no compatibility but the previous versions of the dlls are **not** unregistered beforehand, so the registry keys for the typelibs are not removed and these bogus registry entries point to the new dlls.

Usually I deal with these with an internal registry cleaner tool that can remove typelibs/clsid/interfaces registration based on typelib disk location. You can try moving physical files of the referenced projets to different location on disk and `regsvr32` them there, manually remove references from the project file, restart the IDE and reopen project, finally add references and check that dll location in add reference dialog points to the new files location.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no MISSING references then try compiling the libraries of the project using project compatibility instead of binary compatibility. VB6 can get confused with Binary compatibility when there are multiple libraries being reference in a hierarchy of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but from the top menu - "Project" -> "References" and the missing ones are usually highlighed or say missing next to them.

Answer (score 0):

In Project -> References, double-check the Location of all your references. Your reference might have the right name but could be pointing to another instance of the same DLL.

Comment: For a question as old as this, you really need to make effort to explain why your suggestion solution should work - this is especially important for a question that already has a number of answers.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019, got same error on my old xp laptop in a project being migrated from Excel VBA to VB6. I read all above answers and could not solve the issue (No Missing references to start with and there are not many changes done on the default libraries' locations). What actually solved my problem is kind of strange. I double-clicked and opened each and every form and Designer modules (essentially loading it components to memory) and voila, the error is gone its own. I tried to reproduce the error and it does comeback when I launch the IDE once again. Finally figured out, there is one such bulky userform with lot of control is the culprit. I couldn't figure out exactly which control is causing the dll error but for now the job is done.