# Can't Open VB6 Project - actbar.ocx and dll error

Tags: vb6, ocx

When i tried to open my existing vb6 project in win7, it show actbar.ocx error. Then i register actbar.ocx in SysWOW64 folder and try to open again, it show "could not open all dll" error.

Anybody who ever encountered this error before?

Thanks

Comment: Check the list in Project-References.  Any that show 'Missing' will need to be resolved or removed (and corresponding code removed or changed).  Alternately, it could be some dll(s) that your ocx needs and references itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Error in loading DLL" when compiling DLL in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576442/error-in-loading-dll-when-compiling-dll-in-vb6)

Comment: This is possibly related to Active Toolbar ActiveX. We had same kind of issue until we did manage to find the original installer. Latest we have (working in WIndows 10 x64 with some tweaking) is v1.0.6.5. You have to find your original installer. We also found v1.0.3.6 in our archives... (to help you searching)